# how to show popup menu when touching in Icon

Tags: react-native

https://cmichel.io/how-to-create-a-more-popup-menu-in-react-native/
how I need to call popupmenu from this example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have `UIManagerModule.showPopupMenu` in your modules,
then you can call this class via `UIManager` class

```
import { UIManager, findNodeHandle } from 'react-native'

UIManager.showPopupMenu(
    findNodeHandle(this.state.icon),
    this.props.actions,
    this.onError,
    this.props.onPress
  )
```

It is opened by finding the `reference node` of the `icon` as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/MrToph/1bcd0daa99035e63f427dd2b08256bd9).

It works only on **android** though, and can be followed [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3004)