# How to make dropdown menu in react-navigation in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to make dropdown menu inside navigation bar like WhatsApp has.
Some of dropdown menus are inside navigation bar, some others are outside. The button of dropdown menu item that outside navigation bar wont be triggered, which is the problem.

Using React-Navigation, I set `navigationOption` for navigation that would contain dropdown menu from its child, which is tabs navigation bar, since i want tabs navigation bar bellow it, like WhatsApp has. 
I also put transparent `TouchableHiglight` that will cover the entire app. So, If i press anywhere except the menu button, it would hide the dropdown menus. Just much like WhatsApp has. 
This is the code of my React-Native app:

```
class DropdownMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isHide: true
    }
  }

  render() {
  if (this.state.isHide) {
    return ( 

      //display menu icon

      <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>this.setState({isHide: false})}>  
        <Image source={require("./ic-menu.png")} />
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )}else{
    return ( 

      //show menu items

      <View style={styles.coverPage}>  
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.coverPage} onPress={()=>this.setState({isHide: true})}><View></View></TouchableHighlight>

        <TouchableHighlight><Text>Members</Text></TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight><Text>Settings</Text></TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )}
  }
}
```

Then I put `<DropdownMenu/>` via child's navigationOption of navigation that would contain dropdown menu.

```
ChildTabNav.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
  const headerTitle = routeName;

  return {
    headerTitle,
    headerRight: (
       <DropdownMenu/>
    )
  };
};
```

It's almost work as i expect. Dropdown showed correctly. When I press dropdown menu item on navigation bar area, it's work. Other button is above outside of navigation bar, and it button does not work.
Moreover, if there is any button bellow menu item button, it would trigger the button bellow it whether the button is visually covered by menu item.
I want the button is working on both inside or outside the navigation bar.

Comment: This is an issue on Android as you cannot click on items outside of their view. refer this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513534/react-native-overflow-touchable-is-not-working-in-android/54609457#54609457. I think it's a similar issue which you have a reported.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to go with `UIManager` it goes something like this (Pritish Vaidya's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49764173/2929068))

```
import { UIManager, findNodeHandle } from 'react-native';

class Menu extends Component {
iconRef = createRef();

onError = () => {
   console.log()'
}

openMenu = () => {
  UIManager.showPopupMenu(
    findNodeHandle(this.iconRef),
    ['action1', 'action2', 'action3'],
    this.onError,
    this.props.onPress);
}

render () {
   return(
       <Icon ref={this.iconRef} onPress={this.openMenu} />
   )
}
```

But this will work only in Android and you wont have a proble with click outside and or click in items.

Comment: But i want support both device

Comment: for this, you may want to create two files `index.ios.js` for ios component and another one `index.android.js` for the Android component.

Comment: Use `<Picker>` and `<Modal>` instead, fix the problem.